Can't see GitFlow option in version 23.1.3 Smart Git
In version 23.1.3 of smart git I can't see the usual gitflow option. I want to configure the defaults and use that option to start features etc. How is this meant to be achieved now?
Note i ran the "git flow init" command from the terminal but can't see the additional branches or the usual gitflow option

Be sure to open the Log or Working Tree window (see Window menu). The Standard window does not support Git-Flow, but it comes with its own Feature Flow.
